# Longest common set of two strings

Tags: algorithm, substring

I thought of an interesting problem. There are lots of advanced methods that find longest common substring of two strings. But, if we do not consider the order, how to find the common set quickly? How to optimize the naive algorithm.

```
string1 = 'abcdefgh'
string2 = 'mlfdehjiopfe'
longest_common_set = func(string1, string2)
```

Then, we get the `longest_common_set` is `set(['d','e','f'])`

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? What is the specific problem that you're facing?

Comment: @Andreas Intuitively, it can be solved by traversing, but it may cost much time if we have two long strings. I am not clear how to optimize. The problem is just for fun, I think it is interesting.

Comment: Well, if you have a working code and is looking for a code review, you can check the site guidelines of https://codereview.stackexchange.com. However, it seems that this kind of question does not fit this site since you don't have any attempts and the specific roadblocks you're running into

Answer (score 1):

If you think about set then there are many techniques which you can follow. 
And one of them is -

Determine `longest common sub-sequence` of this two strings (With *path*).
Then take unique characters from the *path*.

You can learn `longest common sub-sequence` from here: https://www.techiedelight.com/longest-common-subsequence/